# Como selecionar linhas que tenham um texto procurando em todas as colunas de um data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, grep

Estou querendo selecionar somente as linhas que tenham o texto "try", similar ao grep no Linux. Segue o exemplo:

```
my.data <- data.frame(
  A = c("prot trypsina catalic", "7", "123", NA, "1419", "ab", "ab", "ab"),
  B = c("1416", "7", "123trypsina", "1011", "1416", "ab", "TRYPSIN", "ab"),
  c = c("b", "a", "trypsina123", "trypsin", "no", "ab", "ab", "ab"),
  d = seq(1:8),
  e = rep("please", 8))
```

O resultado desejado seria como segue a continuação:

```
my.data[c(1,3,4,7),]
                      A           B           c d      e
1 prot trypsina catalic        1416           b 1 please
3                   123 123trypsina trypsina123 3 please
4                  <NA>        1011     trypsin 4 please
7                    ab     TRYPSIN          ab 7 please
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução, em uma linha:

```
my.data[apply(my.data, 1, function(x) any(grepl("tryp", x, ignore.case = TRUE))), ]
#>                       A           B           c d      e
#> 1 prot trypsina catalic        1416           b 1 please
#> 3                   123 123trypsina trypsina123 3 please
#> 4                  <NA>        1011     trypsin 4 please
#> 7                    ab     TRYPSIN          ab 7 please
```

**Explicação:**

A função `grepl` retorna um vetor lógico com a presença do padrão; a opção `ignore.case` é para buscar independente de maiúscula ou minúscula. Por exemplo, para a coluna A:

```
grepl("tryp", my.data$B, ignore.case = TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

`any` é usada para ver se existe alguma ocorrência verdadeira, independente da posição. Por exemplo:

```
any(c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
#> [1] TRUE
```

`apply` aplica uma função à uma dimensão de uma arranjo; no caso de um *data.frame*, 1 indica para aplicar às linhas. O resultado junto com `grepl` e `any` é um vetor lógico indicando as linhas que possuem alguma ocorrência do padrão:

```
apply(my.data, 1, function(x) any(grepl("tryp", x, ignore.case = TRUE)))
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

que é usado para indexar as linhas do *data.frame*, sob a forma `df[vetorlogico, ]`

Comment: Fantastico! Muito, mas muito obrigado! Forte abraço Carlos Eduardo Lagosta

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução utilizando funções do `tidyverse` é a seguinte:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my.data %>%
    filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., pattern = "(?i)tryp")))
#>                       A           B           c d      e
#> 1 prot trypsina catalic        1416           b 1 please
#> 2                   123 123trypsina trypsina123 3 please
#> 3                  <NA>        1011     trypsin 4 please
#> 4                    ab     TRYPSIN          ab 7 please
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

O que o comando acima faz é o seguinte:

- `filter_all` irá filtrar todas as linhas
- `any_vars` escolherá qualquer coluna que satisfaça uma condição lógica
- a condição lógica é determinada por `str_detect`, que selecionará qualquer célula que contenha a string `tryp`, sendo que `(?i)` indica para que não eja feita diferenciação entre maiúsculas ou minúsculas nas letras de `tryp`

Comment: Fantastico! Muito, mas muito obrigado! Forte abraço Marcus Nunes

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.

Comment: Oi Marcu Nunes, bom dia. Eu juro que estou tentando, mas parece que eu não tenho reputação ainda porque obtenho a seguinte mensagem "Obrigado pelo feedback! Votos de usuários com reputação menor que 15 são gravados, porém não alteram de forma pública a pontuação apresentada na postagem." Desculpa mesmo, espero contribuir em outra oportunidade

Comment: Nem esquenta. A contribuição já foi feita. Com o tempo, conforme a tua reputação for aumentando, estes pontos passam a aparecer publicamente. O importante é sempre contribuir com o site, não necessariamente apenas nas respostas para as tuas perguntas, mas sempre que algum conteúdo te ajudar de alguma forma. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Eu que agradeço, forte abraço!